# Variable RMADT has been defined as both character and numeric

Tags: sas

I need help converting RMADT to character or numeric. Any help appreciated

```
DATA Vitali;
SET claims (KEEP = RMADT Item_Number Qty_Authorized) nrclaims 
(KEEP = Arrival_Date Item_Number Qty_Claimed rename=
(Qty_Claimed=Qty_Authorized));
RUN;
```

Comment: Your code as is should run fine.  RMADT isn't being kept in the second dataset.  Are you doing other things in the data step?

Comment: Hi @Joe , yes its a pretty big code that wasn't written by me, is there something I should be looking in it?

Comment: Find the dataset where it's defined as whichever type you do NOT want, use a put/input statement to convert it to the type you DO want, and then run the vitali data step you have here.

Comment: What do you mean "to character or numeric"? What type is this variable right now?

Comment: Its in numeric and I need it to convert to character, its a column. I was able to bypass it because there was another column with the same data in character, I was able to rename it to RMADT

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to convert a column to Numeric, but I was able to bypass it because I had another column with numeric type that had the same data, I renamed that column to RMADT. Thanks everyone